# C# singleton between projects didn't work

Tags: c#, singleton, multiple-projects

I have 3 projects in a solution like This:

1. Xna Game Project (GAME) with reference to Library
2. Library Project (Library)
3. Windows Form Project (WIN) with reference to Library

This project have a multiple project Start up (WIN and GAME).

So, in my Library I have a facade to inject the dependencies between them using a singleton to provide an unified way to use a device plugged into a serial connector.

That's why I'm using a singleton... cause I can not have 2 connections to the same port.

In my other 2 libraries (WIN and GAME) I use the navigator through this facade. But the result was always 2 attempts to instantiate the serial port, so the second one always fails!..

Debugging it, adding a breakpoint in that line:

```
private static readonly LogicalFaccade _instance = new LogicalFaccade();
```

I requested 2 different calls... I thing one from each project (WIN and GAME).

How can I share an unique instance between projects ?

Is something wrong in my code?...

```
public class LogicalFaccade
{
    private static readonly object thredLock = new Object();

    private static readonly LogicalFaccade _instance = new LogicalFaccade();
    public static LogicalFaccade Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private INavigator _navigator;
    public INavigator Navigator
    {
        get
        {
            lock (thredLock)
            {
                if (_navigator == null)
                {
                    _navigator = new SerialNavigator("COM4", 19200, 8);
                }
                return _navigator;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is like to manage the state object across multiple application. So this can be achieve using state server. That means you need to manage a service to get the state of this singleton object.

Comment: if win and game two different program you should use some IPC techniques  . pipe,socket for example .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the implementation you have, you will have a singleton object throw many threads of **a single process**(or EXE). 
When having 3 start-up projects you will have 3 different processes, so using singleton pattern (in the way you have implemented) will not help you.

If your 3 projects(processes) will run on a `single workstation (PC)` you can share the resources by using *locking mechanism* of [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx), a useful sample could be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2982/Using-Win32-Semaphores-in-C).
If they will be distributed on `multiple PCs` you need to use *[inter process communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).*

Some of major options in .Net are: 
[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) 
[Remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/process_communication.aspx/process_communication.aspx) 
[ASP.Net WebSevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) 
[WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011.aspx)
[Socket programing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301275/Chatting-using-CSocket)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with IPC . Here is link for named pipes example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7176/Inter-Process-Communication-in-NET-Using-Named-Pip . hope it be helpfull